# My Ip Address - Windows Vista - ipconfig : Cant find my ip address

Tags: windows, networking

If I type in `ipconfig` I don't get my IP Address.
I get other values but not my IP address.

My Computer:

1. Windows Vista
2. ADSL router (for few computers)
3. My IP is temporary - each time that I connect web it changes.

Comment: Can you explain what you do get back from `ipconfig`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this is what you meant (You have to open Start (the orb), and type `cmd` into the field right there. The following black screen pop ups what you can see on the screenshot. If you fail, try pressin `Win+R` combination which lets you run an application. Type: `cmd` *there* and `ipconfig` into the black screen which comes in.):

[image]

A little description:
Check Description field. Like mine, you can see Local Area.. so its a (or THE) LAN connection. So if you are after this, thar u go. The Wireless goes for the WLan connection obviously, which is disabled here at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

From Microsoft's website: [Find your computer's IP address](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/Find-your-computers-IP-address)

> 1. Open Network and Sharing Center by clicking the Start button , clicking Control Panel, clicking Network and Internet, and then clicking Network and Sharing Center.
> 2. Under Connection, click View status.
> 3. Click Details.
>
> Your computer's IP address appears in the Value column, next to "IPV4 IP Address."

Answer (score 2):

When you said `My Ip is temp each time that i connect web he change`, does that mean you want your external (internet) IP?  ipconfig will only tell you the local IP of your machine.  That's the address your router will use to send your internet bits to you.

To find the external IP, I just use http://www.whatismyip.com